# How can I pass a PowerShell function to a .NET method that takes a Func<T1, T2>?

Tags: powershell

I need to create a .NET object in PowerShell. The signature for the constructor is:

```
public ObjCTor(TClient param1, Func<TClient, IInterface> param2)
```

and the class is defined as:

```
public class ObjCTor<TClient> : IOtherInt1, IOtherInt2 where TClient : ConcreteBase
```

The first parameter is easy enough.  I'm stumped on the second.  How can I pass a PowerShell function as `Func<T1, T2>`?

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax supplied by Jason wasn't quiet correct.  This works:

```
$= New-Object "ObjCTor[TClient]" -ArgumentList $param1,$functionToCall
```

I was also missing the `$args[0]` as a parameter in my scriptblock/delegate.  This is what I should've had:

```
$functionToCall = { Get-Blah $args[0] }
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell can convert a ScriptBlock to a delegate, so something like this might work fine:

```
$sb = { param($t1) $t1 }
New-Object "ObjCTor[CClient, Func[CClient,IInterface]]" -ArgumentList $param1,$sb
```

Note that PowerShell cannot deduce generic type arguments from a ScriptBlock.  In your case, ObjCTor looks like a generic class so type deduction isn't a factor, but if you were calling a generic method, things could get messy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your suggested syntax wasn't quite right but a modified version is (nearly) working: the function argument isn't available to the function.